# MAX(rowid) giving n+1 rows as answer

Tags: mysql, sqlite, rowid

"SELECT max(rowid) from studdetail"
this should give maximum row in the table. And it is  giving at  one place  but at another it is giving n+1(n is the no. of rows).
What can be the reasons?
I read something like hidden row is it that if yes then pls explain.
Thanks

Comment: What does this mean? `And it is giving at one place but at another`

Comment: Which database? You have this tagged for multiple ones? I assume sqlite thanks to the use of the rowid column?

Comment: *""SELECT max(rowid) from studdetail" this should give maximum row in the table"* It also assumes you never delete the "last" `(max(rowid))` record from the table.. Also you are talking about SQLite because you are talking about rowid?

Comment: Oh, wait. Are you expecting the max rowid to equal the number of rows in the table? That's not how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max(rowid)` will return the highest rowid.

If rows have been deleted, or that rowid's have been skipped ([can occur](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#the_autoincrement_keyword)), or the rowid has been manually set, the highest allocated rowid may be greater than the number of actual rows. That is the rowid value for a row does not need to exactly represent it's position.

`count(rowid)` would return the number of rows.

## Example

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thetable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thetable (mycolumn);
INSERT INTO thetable VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');
SELECT max(rowid), count(rowid) FROM thetable;
DELETE FROM thetable WHERE mycolumn = 'C';
SELECT max(rowid), count(rowid) FROM thetable;
INSERT INTO thetable (rowid,mycolumn) VALUES(26,'Z');
SELECT max(rowid), count(rowid) FROM thetable;
```

The first result, both max(rowid) and count(rowid) are 5 :-

[image]

The second result, as an intermediate row has been deleted, shows a discrepancy between the `max(rowid)` **(5)** and `count(rowid)` **(4)** :-

[image]

The third result, as a rowid value has been forced to be 26, shows an even greater discrepancy (26 v 5) :-

[image]